# Cloudflare Proxy Slow HTTP Download Speed

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, cloudflare

I have Cloudflare proxy set-up on my server and would like to keep it that way how-ever I noticed some issues today when running some tests.

When downloading a 100BM.bin file from http://example.com the download speed is super slow at roughly 148kb/s. If I change the domain to my ip address thus bypassing the cloudflare proxy I can max out my home connection.

Has anyone experienced this before? What can I do to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You have CloudFlare set up "on your server", or do you have the CloudFlare CDN configured to proxy and cache your server? Have you set up caching headers properly on the web server so CloudFlare caches the file? What's the ping to your server (via IP), and what's the ping to CloudFlare (via domain name)? Please edit your question rather than answering in comments.

Comment: After contacting their support they told me that they had rate limited my account. This was causing the problem. I turned the proxy off and all is working well now.

Comment: Interesting. Please answer your own question, as it means people won't come in trying to help. Give any additional information you have as well, such as why they rate limited your account, if you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking with Cloudflare they told me that my account had been flagged because of a spike in bandwidth use in their London facility. They ended up putting a rate limit on my website so downloads could not exceed 150kbps.

I have since turned off the Cloudflare proxy and everything is working well now.

Comment: Are you using the free CloudFlare plan? Curious if you can tell us how much bandwidth / data you put through CloudFlare to make them limit your account?

Comment: They limited my account because they thought I was using Cloudflare for streaming.

Comment: Happened to me last night.  CF reports 130k requests for yday.  Users reported atrocious speeds (30/40K and I tested and got even less).  I switched CF off and went direct and also tested via another CDN and got way more normal speeds.  Completely useless service if they degrade your performance.